# How to parse the AWS S3 Path (s3://<bucket name>/<key>) using the AWSSDK.S3 in C# in order to get the bucket name & key

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have a s3 path => s3://[bucket name]/[key]

```
s3://bn-complete-dev-test/1234567890/renders/Irradiance_A.png
```

and I need get the bucket_name and the key separately:

```
var s3PathParsed = parseS3Path("s3://bn-complete-dev-test/1234567890/renders/Irradiance_A.png");

s3PathParsed.BucketName == "bn-complete-dev-test"
s3PathParsed.Key == "1234567890/renders/Irradiance_A.png"
```

**how to I could parse in the correct way *using the AWS SDK*?**

1) I am parsing manually (using a regular expression) and **work fine but i am not comfortable**:

```
public class S3Path : IS3Path
{
    private const string _s3PathRegex = @"[s|S]3:\/\/(?<bucket>[^\/]*)\/(?<key>.*)";

    public S3Path(string s3Path)
    {
        Path = s3Path;

        var rx = new Regex(_s3PathRegex).Match(s3Path);

        if (!rx.Success || rx.Groups.Count != 3)
            throw new Exception($"the S3 Path '{s3Path}' is wrong.");

        BucketName = rx.Groups[1].Value;
        Key = rx.Groups[2].Value;
    }

    public string Path { get; }

    public string BucketName { get; }

    public string Key { get; }
}
```

2) I used the AmazonS3Uri from AWWSDK.S3:

```
string GetBucketNameFromS3Uri(string s3Uri)
{
    return new AmazonS3Uri(s3Uri).Bucket;            
}
```

I called the method:

```
GetBucketNameFromS3Uri("s3://sunsite-complete-dev-test/1234567890/renders/Irradiance_A.png");
```

and i have the following error:

System.ArgumentException: 'Invalid S3 URI - hostname does not appear to be a valid S3 endpoint'

3) Also I try

```
string GetBucketNameFromS3Uri(string s3Uri)
{
    return new AmazonS3Uri(new Uri(s3Uri)).Bucket;            
}
```

with the same error.

I created a new thread in AWS Forum with this issue: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=304401

Comment: There's obviously an issue with the S3 URI you are using. Can you update your question to include the actual URI? It should be something like `https://bucket.s3-aws-region.amazonaws.com/key`.

Comment: I need parse the S3 path (s3://<bucket_name>/<key>), not the URL to the object

Comment: FYI since`s3://<bucket_name>/<key>` is a URL, you can use the URL parser in your language of choice

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have an object URL (`https://bn-complete-dev-test.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/1234567890/renders/Irradiance_A.pnlet`), you can use [`AmazonS3Uri`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/TS3Uri.html):

```cs
// using Amazon.S3.Util

var uri = new AmazonS3Uri(urlString); 

var bucketName = uri.Bucket;
var key = uri.Key;
```

If you have an S3 URI (`s3://bn-complete-dev-test/1234567890/renders/Irradiance_A.png`) then it is a bit more involved:

```cs
using System;

public static class S3
{
    public static Tuple<string, string> TryParseS3Uri(string x)
    {
        try
        {
            var uri = new Uri(x);

            if (uri.Scheme == "s3")
            {
                var bucket = uri.Host;
                var key = uri.LocalPath.Substring(1);

                return new Tuple<string, string>(bucket, key);
            }

            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var ex2 = ex as UriFormatException;

            if (ex2 == null)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's an F# version:

```ml
open System

let tryParseS3Uri (x : string) =
  try
    let uri = Uri x

    if uri.Scheme = "s3"
    then
      let bucket = uri.Host
      let key = uri.LocalPath.Substring 1

      Some (bucket, key)
    else
      None

  with
    | :? UriFormatException -> None
    | exn -> raise exn
```

Comment: This does not work with an S3 path like "s3://bn-complete-dev-test/1234567890/renders/Irradiance_A.png".  It only works with the URL to the object.

Comment: @Trisped Good point. We can use the `Uri` class from the standard library for this.

Answer (score 16):

In Java, We can do something like

```
AmazonS3URI s3URI = new AmazonS3URI("s3://bucket/folder/object.csv");
S3Object s3Object = s3Client.getObject(s3URI.getBucket(), s3URI.getKey());
```

Comment: Didn't know that helper object existed. Great idea.

Comment: Does this actually work in Java? Because in .NET it throws an exception of `Invalid S3 URI - hostname does not appear to be a valid S3 endpoint`. I am guessing itt only works on http(s) URLs, which makes sense I guess as a URI doesn't have to contain the protocol. Kind of silly for Amazon not to take this into account though.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the scala version and usage of the regex.

```scala
val regex = "s3a://([^/]*)/(.*)".r
val regex(bucketName, key) = "s3a://my-bucket-name/myrootpath/mychildpath/file.json"

println(bucketName) // my-bucket-name
println(key)        // myrootpath/mychildpath/file.json
```

Answer (score 1):

The AWSSDK.S3 has not a path parser, we need parse manually. You could use the following class that work fine:

```
public class S3Path 
{
    private const string _s3PathRegex = @"[s|S]3:\/\/(?<bucket>[^\/]+)\/(?<key>.+)";

    public S3Path(string s3Path)
    {
        Path = s3Path;

        var rx = new Regex(_s3PathRegex).Match(s3Path);

        if (!rx.Success)
            throw new Exception($"the S3 Path '{s3Path}' is wrong.");

        BucketName = rx.Groups["bucket"].Value;
        Key = rx.Groups["key"].Value;
    }

    public string Path { get; }

    public string BucketName { get; }

    public string Key { get; }
}
```

[I created a thread in AWS Forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=304401&tstart=0) to report the missing functionality.

Comment: You can't have `rx.Success == true` and have `rx.Groups.Count` be anything other than 3.  Otherwise it wouldn't match the regex.  Also, the whole point of naming the groups was so you could use `rx.Groups["Bucket"].Value` and `rx.Groups["Key"].Value`.

Comment: What about https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/TS3Uri.html ?

Answer (score 1):

Use AWSSDK.S3

```
public (string bucket, string objectKey, Amazon.RegionEndpoint region) Parse(string s3) 
{
   if (!Amazon.S3.Util.AmazonS3Uri.TryParseAmazonS3Uri(s3, out Amazon.S3.Util.AmazonS3Uri s3Uri))
   {
     throw new System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(s3));
   }
   return (s3Uri.Bucket, s3Uri.Key, s3Uri.Region);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this regex will give you what you want:

```
s3:\/\/(?<bucket>[^\/]*)\/(?<key>.*)
```

The bucketname is the first part of the S3 path and the key is everything after the first forward slash.

Comment: I want to avoid the use of manual solutions like regular expressions because it is a manual method, I want to use the AWS SDK for S3

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think you're going to file a solution in the Amazon SDK as it seems to expect the `http://bucket.s3.aws-region.amazonaws.com/Key` format for its URIs

Comment: Yes, I agree. AWS SDK has not that functionality at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

For Javascript version you can use [amazon-s3-uri](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-s3-uri)

```
const AmazonS3URI = require('amazon-s3-uri')
 
try {
  const uri = 'https://bucket.s3-aws-region.amazonaws.com/key'
  const { region, bucket, key } = AmazonS3URI(uri)
} catch((err) => {
  console.warn(`${uri} is not a valid S3 uri`) // should not happen because `uri` is valid in that example
})
```